# jQuery - Help combining multiple mouseenter/mouseleave events

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, mouseenter

Sorry if this is a noob question but is there a way to combine these mouseenter/mouseleave events?

```
$('.home').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#display_home:hidden').fadeIn(400); 
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         $('#display_home').hide()
     }); 

     $('.about').mouseenter(function(){
         $('#display_about:hidden').fadeIn(400);
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         $('#display_about').hide();
     });

     $('.contact').mouseenter(function(){
         $('#display_contact:hidden').fadeIn(400);
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         $('#display_contact').hide();
     });

     $('.services').mouseenter(function(){
         $('#display_services:hidden').fadeIn(400);
     }).mouseleave(function(){ 
         $('#display_services').hide();
     });
```

I've tried various methods by various programmers.  I'm trying to hide/show multiple divs independently by mousing over the li class linked to each div by the `mouseenter` function but I'm new to jQuery and can't seem to find a solution.  I know there has to be a cleaner way of doing this, I just haven't found one yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[example](http://testsite00.hostoi.com)

Thanks

html:

```
<div id="right_nav">
    <div id='display_home'><img src="images/gallery/home.png" width="605" height="300" /></div>
    <div id='display_about'><img src="images/gallery/about us.png" width="605" height="300" /></div>
    <div id='display_contact'><img src="images/gallery/Contact Us.png" width="605" height="300" /></div>
    <div id='display_services'><img src="images/gallery/Services.png" width="605" height="300" /></div> 
  </div>
<div id="thumb">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" width="82" height="23" /></li>
        <li class="about"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/about us.png" width="130" height="24" /></li>
        <li class="contact"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" width="150" height="23" /></li>
        <li class="services"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" width="113" height="24" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $('.home, .about, .contact, ,services').hover(function(){
    $('#display_'+$(this).attr('class')+':hidden').fadeIn(400); 
 }, function() {
     $('#display_'+$(this).attr('class')).hide()
 });
```

EDIT

Perhaps it is even better to use the data attribute instead of the classname:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="home" data-name="home"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/home.png" width="82" height="23" /></li>
    <li class="about" data-name="about"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/about us.png" width="130" height="24" /></li>
    <li class="contact" data-name="contact"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Contact Us.png" width="150" height="23" /></li>
    <li class="services" data-name="services"><img src="images/gallery/thumb/Services.png" width="113" height="24" /></li>
  </ul>

 $('#thumb li').hover(function(){
    $('#display_'+$(this).data('name')+':hidden').fadeIn(400); 
 }, function() {
     $('#display_'+$(this).data('name')).stop().hide();
 });
```

This way you can change the classes or add classes without breaking it.

Comment: I'd change `$('.home, .about, .contact, ,services').hover(function(){` to `$('li', $("#thumb").hover(function(){` so that it doesn't matter when the names change, or when new menu entries are added

Comment: Thank you. I went with your second example and  it worked with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div#thumb li').hover(function(){ // mouseover
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    var divToShow = $('div#display_'+className);
    divToShow.fadeIn(400);
},
function(){ // mouseout
    // just hide all divs
    $('div#right_nav div').stop().hide();
});
```

So here, I've assumed that the class names of the lis directly relate the ids of the divs you want to hide/show.

The first function (mouseover) therefore gets the classname of the li you've moused over, it then adds it to the prefix `div#display_` in order to build the id of the div you want to show, and then fades in that element.

The mouseout function just hides all the divs. The `stop()` stops the animation, if its part way through fading in.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#thumb ul li').mouseenter(function(){
        $('#right_nav div').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(400); 
     }).mouseleave(function(){
         $('#right_nav div').hide()
     });
```

This is the simplest version supposing the content is in the same order, without a need to come back to your script and edit.

Comment: This assumes that the divs in `#right_nav` are in the same order as the lis which they might not always be. If the classes directly correlate to the ids of the divs then that might be a better way to do it, as per my example.

Comment: the example shows them in this order so it would seem to be appropriate :P

Comment: fair enough, i just thought I'd make the point so as there is no confusion. :)